# C++ Instantiate template template class

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to implement my own container (in my demonstration called Manager), which stores another templated container (e.g `Node<T>`).
Therefore I am trying to instantiate an object like `Mgr<Node<T>>`.
After reading through all of the *template template*-articles on here, I came to the following demonstration code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Node {
    T data;
    int id;
};

template<template<typename> class Container, typename T>
struct Mgr {
    Container<T> nodes;
    int id;
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << this->id;
    }
};

int main() {
    Mgr<Node<char>, char> mgr;
    mgr.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this still gives me the error message: `type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<template<class> class Container, class T> struct Mgr...Expected a class template, got Node<char>`
Is my function definition wrong, or do my instantiation parameters incorrect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`template<typename> class Container` expect that you pass a template as `Container`, `Node<char>` is not a template, it's a concrete type.

You want
`Mgr<Node, char> mgr;`

Comment: That's *if* you need a template template parameter. Chances are, all you need is a concrete container.